# Is it possible to run the same Ubuntu Image on two different machines?

Tags: boot, sync

I run Ubuntu 14.04lts on my laptop. I use it for college, work, and basically all on the go activities. Everything about it is perfect and exactly how I want it, with about a year's worth of slow customizations and changes made. I also have an Ubuntu 14.04lts boot on my desktop, but I do not access it as much since it is not customized and up to date with all the software I need like my laptop. It is essentially the default distribution, I have not done much in the realm of customization.

Is it possible for me to somehow have the same OS run on both my laptop and desktop without remoting into one of the two computers? IE, I do some programming on my laptop, and all my code is on my desktop the next time I boot it up. Or if I make a change to some system file it also effects the desktop, because they are the same OS synced and just booted on a different system.

Is anything like that possible? I would love to just take my OS from my laptop and sync it with my desktop somehow. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do that.

1. Download Clonezilla from [here,](http://clonezilla.org/)
2. Burn the ISO to a DVD.
3. Connect an external hard drive to your laptop or you can make do with your internal hard drive too.
4. Now, boot from your DVD and clone your current laptop OS.
5. Install the clone to your desktop.

That's it. But I recommend reading their instructions first because there are some conditions that need to be fulfilled when cloning an OS.

You might want to follow this [tutorial](http://www.geekyprojects.com/cloning/how-to-use-clonezilla-tutorial/) if you are doing this for the first time.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Rsync

Need to exclude a few key files like

/etc/hostname  (unique for each machine)

/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules (because the mac addresses will be different)

and the live directories 
/proc /dev /sys

You'd want the disk layouts to be the same, like everything in /dev/sda1

You'd need to enable root logins so you can clobber everything in the target

You'd need a complete backup of the target (desktop) before you start, because you could easily make it unusable.

The target would need to be running when you initiate the rsync

Also a live usb on hand so you can restart the target and retry.

You'd need ssh keys in place for rsync

```
ssh-copy-id root@target:
```

Other options like clonezilla, fsarchiver, partimage, g4l, remastersys won't give you the ongoing updates you want without lots of messy reboots into live CDs.

```
rsync   --one-file-system \
       --recursive \
       --links \
       --perms \
       --times \
       --group \
       --owner \
       --devices \
       --specials \
       --verbose \
       --delete-during \
       --exclude-from rsyncfilterfile.conf \
     / root@targetmachinename: \
                     >> logfilename.log \
                    2>> logfilename.err
```

rsyncfilterfile.conf

```
- /etc/hostname
- /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
- /dev/
- /lib/modules/*/volatile/
- /proc/
- /sys/
- /var/lock/
- /var/run/
- /var/spool/
- /var/tmp/
- /tmp/
```